# Core Data - Best way to save a "number of items"

Tags: iphone, core-data

The user will have a static list of items to choose from. Using a Picker View they will choose one of the items and then select how many of them they want.

Whats the best way to save this in core data? A Struct?

```
struct order {
    NSInteger item;
    NSInteger numberOf;
};
```

Or some sort of relationship?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Core Data you would create an entity to model the users choices.

Assuming the item is just a name then you would have an entity something like this:

```
ChoiceEntity{
    itemName=string;
    quantity=int;
}
```

If items have their own entity, it would look like this:

```
ChoiceEntity{
    quantity=int;
    item <<--(required,nullify)--> ItemEntity;
}

ItemEntity {
    // ... attributes of items. 
    choices <--(optional, cascade)-->> ChoiceEntity;
}
```

For simple data without relationships, you can think of Core Data entities as simple structs. (In fact, under the hood, that's what they are.)

Comment: So for example if ChoiceEntity was one item on an order would I put ChoiceEntity as a to - many relationship in my OrderEntity. If that makes sense?

So a customer could put in a single order:

Apples x 2,
Bread x 1,
Chocolate x 10